# How to include Drupal 7 properties in a .info.yml file for Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am in the process of porting a Drupal 7 theme to Drupal 8 (this is part of migrating a whole website over). I know that the first step is to create the directory structure and modify the `.info` file. However, I'm stuck in a few places.

My previous `.info` file has the following properties:

```
name: Theme
type: theme
description: 'My custom theme'
core: 8.x
engine: twig
screenshot: screenshot.png
base theme: omega

regions:
    page_top: 
    page_bottom:
    content:
    other stuff:

zones:
    user:
    branding:
    header:
    preface:
    content:
    postscript:
    footer:

css:
    global.css:
        name:
        description:
        options:
            weight:

stylesheets:
    all:
        -some css files from my cs folder

scripts:
    -some scripts from my js folder

grids:
    theme_default:
        name:
        layouts:
            wide:
            normal:
            narrow:
        columns:
            full:
            24:
            16:
            12:

settings:
    a ton of settings:

version: "8.x"
core: "8.x"
project: "omega"
```

However, I see that not all of these are valid keys (as seen in `https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file`). I understand that the `stylesheets` and `scripts` properties are dealt with by libraries now, but that still leaves the `zones`, `css`, `grids`, and `settings` properties. Should I leave them as is, or is there a special method to dealing with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in the [Drupal 8 theme info file documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file) the supported key names in the theme info files are

```
name (required)
type (required)
description (optional)
package (optional)
core (required)
php (optional)
version (optional)
libraries (optional)
libraries-override (optional)
libraries-extend (optional)
base theme (recommended)
hidden (optional)
engine (optional)
logo (optional)
screenshot (optional)
regions (optional)
regions_hidden (optional)
features (optional)
stylesheets-remove (deprecated)
ckeditor_stylesheets (optional)
```

So your theme info file can have only these properties. Anything else will be ignored.

However, drupal 8 allows themes and modules to have any amount of custom configuration that can be loaded via the Configuration Schema system. You can define all your other settings using this. You can read more about it from the following

- [Defining and using Custom Configuration in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8)
- [Configuration schema/metadata](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata)
- [Creating advanced theme settings in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-advanced-theme-settings)